# Gimp: How can I control blur strength via data from a channel?

Tags: gimp, blur, channel

I want to apply a blur, but for the blur distance (strength) to depend on the corresponding value of a given channel.

For example, if my control channel has a gradient from black at the top to white at the bottom, I want the resulting image to not be blurred at all at the top, and steadily get more and more blurred towards the bottom, until at the bottom it is at a maximum strength.

This is not the same as doing a quick mask, setting a gradient top to bottom, switching off quick mask so that becomes a graded selection, then running a blur at high strength over the whole thing.

Is this possible in Gimp?

Comment: that would be [variable blur](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-filter-variable-blur.html)?

Comment: That looks like exactly what I want; thank you. It's not on my blur menu though. Looking deeper, it seems it was added in version 2.10.20, and I'm on 2.10.18. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Filters > Blur > Variable Blur

Comment: [see example in use](https://i.imgur.com/2WOTc0t.jpeg)